# editing file using fseek

Tags: c, fseek

can you help me figure out what's the problem in my code.. i wanted to edit a specific line.... thnx

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (){
    char arr[50];
    char arr2[50];
    char arr3[50];     
    FILE *stream = NULL;
    FILE *stream2 = NULL;
    stream = fopen("studentinfo.txt", "rt");
    stream2 = fopen("studentinfo2.txt", "w+");
    char* token;
    char dlm[] = ",";

    printf("Enter student id: ");
    scanf("%s", arr2);
    printf("New student id: ");
    scanf("%s", arr3);
    while(!feof(stream)){
       fgets(arr,100,stream);
       fprintf(stream2,"%s",arr);
       token = strtok(arr,dlm);
       if(strcmp(arr2, token)==0){
       fseek ( stream2 , 0 , SEEK_CUR );
       fputs ( arr3 , stream2 );
       }
    }
    fclose ( stream2 );
    fclose ( stream );
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I believe that if you give your variables more meaningful names, that will make understanding your code easier and support you in finding errors. You already know that `arr2` is an array by looking at the definition; why don't you provide additional meaning by naming that variable e.g. `student_id`, and `arr3 -> new_student_id`, or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot "edit specific lines". You can replace the bytes that are currently in the file, but if you need to replace with fewer or more bytes then you need to rewrite the rest of the file after them.